# Why are all files in AnkhSVN solution marked as new after installing TortoiseSVN?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, svn, tortoisesvn, ankhsvn

After installing TortoiseSVN 1.6.0, all files loaded into an AnkhSVN enabled Visual Studio 2008 project are marked as new (blue +).

I have tried re-installing AnkhSVN 2.0.6347 and checkout the repository into a new "clean" folder. However neither seem to resolve the problem.

My question is kind of two fold, is there a resolution to this issue and if there is an in-compatibility between the two products (i.e. different SVN bindings?) is there a way to tell which combination of AnkhSVN and TortoiseSVN are going to play nice with each other.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I noticed this too a couple of days ago. This happened because Tortoise converted your working copy to 1.6 version and Ankh doesn't know how to read it.

The solution is simple: I installed the latest **daily** build of Ankh (http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/daily/) and now everything works like a charm.

Comment: Don't know why I didn't think of this, thanks for the link and making my life that bit easier.

Answer (score 3):

I can verify that this works, too.

One thing that I ran into was that I uninstalled the older version before installing the new daily build version (I installed AnkhSvn-Daily-2.1.6649.29.msi), but once I installed the new version I didn't have ***any*** source code control integration whatsoever in Visual Studio 2008!

As it turned out, when you uninstall AnkhSVN your source code control provider gets set to "None", and you have to go to "Tools | Options | Source Control" and set it back to AnkhSVN.

Once you do that, you're good to go with Visual Studio integration and TortoiseSVN 1.6.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly this solution does not work for anyone using VS2003 since there is no daily build (SVN 1.6) for the 1.x branch of AnkhSVN.

The AnkhSVN team has stated that they are too busy right now to update AnkhSVN 1.x (ie the VS2002/VS2003 version), so it looks like unless someone is willing to help them with it (it’s open-source), there may not be an SVN1.6 version for VS2003 for a while.